# Objective C - UIWebview - Convert javascript text range to objective c object and vice versa

Tags: javascript, objective-c, uiwebview, range

I have a UIWebview in which html content is being displayed. when a user selects a piece of text, I want to save the range of that text using objective c, then recall that saved range at a later stage to reselect the text in the UIWebview.

The closest I could get is the following javascript:

```
var selection = window.getSelection();
var range = selection.getRangeAt(selection.rangeCount);
```

But I have no clue as to how to return the range object back to objective c to save it and reuse it later on. Could any one point me into the right direct?

Thanks,
EZFrag

Comment: Take a look at `-stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:`

Comment: Ok, could you please explain how I can convert a range to a string? Please note that the range contains a lot of objects and variable which I need to retain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could serialize the range to a string representing the paths through the DOM to get to the start and end points. My [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy) library has [a serializer module that does this](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/SerializerModule), but for just Mobile Safari, relying on a relatively large library just for this task may be overkill. For a more lightweight script that uses the same idea, see Martin Honnen's one here: http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/javascript/storingSelection1.html

Comment: i just found and successfully implemented it about 30 minutes ago. Thanks ;)

Comment: @EZFrag, Can you please post your solution here?